# Combine multiple columns of pandas data frame to one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe df as follows such that it's the number of columns vary time to time:

```
  Column 1     Column 2   
0        A        E  
1        B        F  
2        C        G  
3        D        H
```

I need to combine the columns into one such that it looks like as given below:

```
        column 3  
0         A,E  
1         B,F  
2         C,G  
3         D,H
```

For rows to combine into one the following is the code. I need something like that which will not specify the column names.

```
df = df.stack().to_frame().T  
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(*c) for c in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [52]: df.Column1 += ',' + df.pop('Column2')

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
  Column1
0     A,E
1     B,F
2     C,G
3     D,H
```

or

```
In [56]: df['Column3'] = df.pop('Column1') + ',' + df.pop('Column2')

In [57]: df
Out[57]:
  Column3
0     A,E
1     B,F
2     C,G
3     D,H
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [77]: df
Out[77]:
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0       A       E       I
1       B       F       J
2       C       G       K
3       D       H       L

In [78]: res = pd.DataFrame({'ColX': df.add(',').sum(axis=1).str.rstrip(',')}, df.index)

In [79]: res
Out[79]:
    ColX
0  A,E,I
1  B,F,J
2  C,G,K
3  D,H,L
```

Comment: Is there any way of not specifying the column names? Because the  number columns vary time to time. I've edited my question,please refer it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with `.join` -

```
pd.DataFrame({'Out':[",".join(i) for i in df.values]})
```

Sample run -

```
In [375]: df
Out[375]: 
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0       A       E       I
1       B       F       J
2       C       G       K
3       D       H       L

In [376]: pd.DataFrame({'Out':[",".join(i) for i in df.values]})
Out[376]: 
     Out
0  A,E,I
1  B,F,J
2  C,G,K
3  D,H,L
```

Comment: @NayanaMadhu Good to hear that :)